# Count down date - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I'm using this below plugin with default countdown:

```
http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
```

I've problem in setting the countdown time, the default countdown is:

```
var newYear = new Date(); 
newYear = new Date(newYear.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 1); 
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: newYear});
```

I need countdown like below, so show can I convert the above date into below. I just need countdown for 5 mints:

**0(days)-0(hours)-4(mints)-60(seconds)**

Comment: So set `until` to a time that is 5 minutes from now...

Comment: yes, that is, how can that be possbile

Comment: Really?! Just look at the sample code! It defines a `Date` for newyears and then uses it as the `until` parameter in for the countdown. You should be able to work out how to make it count down to some other date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `setMinutes` and `getMinutes` like this:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + 5);
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: d});
```

Comment: Great @Kristoffer . It shows 0 hours - 4 mints - 60 second. Is it possible to add 0 day with it?